# Listener for fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I have a fragment object, is there a way I could get notified of the lifecycle methods of that fragment ?

One possible way to do this is to implement this mechanism in my fragment and the fragment notifies the listeners, but this requires boilerplate code which I need to add in all the methods of the fragment. Is there a support for this at the Android platform level ?

Comment: Only libraries like [LightCicle](https://github.com/soundcloud/lightcycle) or [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the libraries @tynn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can register a [`FragmentLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks.html) instance using `supportFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(callback)`. The callback exposes all lifecycle events of a fragment, and is active until the fragment is destroyed (in which case the callback is automatically unregistered for you).

Comment: Is it only for v25?